# How to embed or nest ruby expression inside string interpolation

Tags: ruby, expression, string-interpolation

I want to embed or nest a Ruby expression inside string interpolation, and have it evaluated.  Something like this, though this doesn't work:

`"#{is_true? ? 'True' : #{false_for_x? ? 'False for X' : 'False for Y'}}"`

Can I do this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation has no sense outside string literals; probably you want this:

```
"#{is_true? ? 'True' : "#{false_for_x? ? 'False for X' : 'False for Y'}"}"
```

Or this (better):

```
"#{is_true? ? 'True' : (false_for_x? ? 'False for X' : 'False for Y')}"
```